# Why does positive definite guarantee uniqueness? (Peter J Olver PDE book chapter 9)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-transformations, positive-definite, self-adjoint-operators

I recently picked up Peter J Olver's "Introduction to Partial Differential Equations" again (Read the full text [here](https://www.usb.ac.ir/FileStaff/3223_2019-10-28-13-12-55.pdf)). I am on chapter 9, "A General Framework for Linear PDEs". The book is dealing with linear operators in fairly general terms. There is a certain theorem that I cannot understand, however. Page 355 in the linked text. Here, $U$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ and $S\in\operatorname{End}(U)$ is **positive definite**, i.e $\langle u,Su\rangle>0~~\forall u\in U\setminus\{0\}$. Here is the proposition:

> ### Proposition 9.19.

> If $S>0$ *[NB: this is just an abbreviation for positive definiteness]* then $\ker S=\{0\}$. As a consequence, a positive definite linear system $Su=f$ with $f\in\operatorname{range}S$ must have a unique solution.

The first bit, $\ker S=\{0\}$ I understand. However, the next bit I don't get. I'm assuming $f\in\operatorname{range}S$ just means that the equation has *at least one* solution. But why the positive definiteness of $S$ implies this solution is unique? I don't know. The book has just finished covering the Fredholm Alternative, but since we have no information about the adjoint $S^*$ I don't think it helps.

At least in the finite dimensional case, if $\mathbf{S}$ is a positive definite matrix then it is [definitely invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059566/explain-proof-that-any-positive-definite-matrix-is-invertible), so the system $\mathbf{S}\boldsymbol{u}=\boldsymbol{f}$ definitely has a unique solution since we can just write
$$\boldsymbol u=\mathbf{S}^{-1}\boldsymbol f$$
But I don't see how to generalize this to the infinite dimensional case.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well if $Su=f$ and $Sv=f$ then $S(u-v)=0$. I.e. $u-v\in\ker S$.

Comment: @Ali Goodness, how silly of me to miss this... if you add this as an answer I will accept it so to mark this question as resolved.

Comment: I'll try, but I've had longer answers deleted before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Su=f$ and $Sv=f$ then $S(u-v)=0$. Which is to say $u-v\in \ker S$.